# Copy sheet to another document to replace existing

Tags: google-sheets

I have such problem and half-of-solution already.

I've an active document with couple of sheets referring to each other. I need to do some changes in formulas, test it and ably implement the changes.

I've figured to make a copy of the sheet where I need to make changes to the side draft. There I make changes and tests and after that I'd like to copy the sheet back to the original document.

For now Google copies the sheet to the destination document as "Copy of Sheetname". Then I delete Sheetname sheet and rename the copy to Sheetname.

The problem is that the cells in other sheets which were referring to the original Sheetname now return #REF! error and I can't see any way to recalculate them efficiently.

Any (great) ideas? :)

Comment: If my understanding for your situation is correct, in my environment, when I carry out manually your situation, ``#REF`` occurs. But ``#REF`` is removed by reloading the document. When I carry out your situation by a script, no ``#REF`` occurs. So I thought that it might depend on the speed which detects the change by Spreadsheet.

Comment: I tried to refresh and reload document but the errors stood there still.

Comment: I thought that I may misunderstand your question. I tried as follows. 1. Prepare 2 Spreadsheets A and B. 2. In Spreadsheet A, ``=IMPORTRANGE("ID of Spreadsheet B", "Sheet1!A1")`` and put "sample" in "A1" of Spreadsheet B. 3. Copy Sheet1 of Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet A. 4. Delete Sheet1 and rename "Copy of Sheet1" to "Sheet1". 5. Reload. Is my understanding for your situation correct?

Comment: Not sure really :)

What I've had on my mind was:
1. Prepare 2 Spreadsheets A and B.
2. In Spreadsheet A prepare Sheet1 and Sheet2.
3. In Sheet2 put "sample" to A1.
4. In Sheet1 put "=Sheet2!A1".
5. Copy Sheet2 to Spreadsheet B.
6. Make any changes to this copy in Spreadsheet B.
7. Copy Sheet2 back from Spreadsheet B to A.
8. Delete the original Sheet2 from Spreadsheet A.
9. Rename the very last "Copy of Sheet2" to "Sheet2" in A.
Then in Sheet1 #REF! appears and stays.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I could confirm the same situation by both the manual and script operation. I thought the sheetname in the A1Notation might be bound to the sheet ID. So as a workaround, I modified a little your flow as follows.

Comment: 1. Prepare 2 Spreadsheets A and B. 2. In Spreadsheet A prepare Sheet1 and Sheet2. 3. In Sheet2 put "sample" to A1. 4. In Sheet1 put "=Sheet2!A1". 5. Copy Sheet2 to Spreadsheet B. 6. Make any changes to this copy in Spreadsheet B. 7. Copy Sheet2 back from Spreadsheet B to A. 8. Copy the all range from the copied sheet to existing Sheet2 using [``copyto(range)``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options). 9. Delete the copied sheet. By this, in my environment, ``#REF`` is avoided.